# Issue with @Transactional and @Retryable

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions, spring-retry

I not able to perform DB operations in a transaction if I add `@Retryable` from spring-retry library. This is how my code structure looks like:

```
    public class ExpireAndSaveTrades {
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = MyException.class)
    public void expireAndSaveTrades(List<Trade> trades) {
        try {
            // these two MUST be executed in one transaction
            trades.forEach(trade -> dao.expireTrades(trade));
            dao.saveTrades(trades);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new MyException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}

public class Dao {
    @Retryable(value = CannotAcquireLockException.class,
            maxAttempts = 3,
            stateful = true,
            backoff = @Backoff(delay = 300, multiplier = 3))
    public void expireTrades(Trade trade) {
    try {
          tradeRepository.expire(trade.getId(), trade.getNewStopDate());
    } catch (CannotAcquireLockException e) {
          expireTrade(trade);
        }

    }

    @Retryable(value = CannotAcquireLockException.class,
            maxAttempts = 3,
            stateful = true,
            backoff = @Backoff(delay = 300, multiplier = 3))
    public void saveTrades(List<Trades> trades) {
    try {
          tradeRepository.saveAll(trades)
    } catch (CannotAcquireLockException e) {
              saveTrades(trades);
            }
    }
}

public interface TradeRepository extends JpaRepository<Trade, Integer> {
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "update trade set stop_date=:new_stop_date where id=:id", nativeQuery = true)
    void expire(@Param("id") int id, @Param("new_stop_date") String newStopDate);
}
```

So there is where I am right now:

1. Without using stateful (i.e. stateful is set to `false` by default) - retry happens successfully but then at the end of it, I see this exception: `org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only` and the data which was updated/saved after multiple retries is rolled back in the database table
2. stateful = true - retry doesn't happen anymore

I have gone through many SO posts and blogs but couldn't find the solution to my problem. Can anybody here please help me out ?

**EDIT:** updated my question to add try-catch block With this the spring-retry doesn't kick in ( I know because I added a listener to `@Retryable` to log the `retryContext`. I dont see the log getting printed. Also the transaction silently rolls back if there was a CannotAcquireLockException

```
@Override
    public <T, E extends Throwable> void onError(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback, Throwable throwable) {
        LOGGER.info("Retry Context - {}", context);
    }
```

Comment: Please update the question with the next things: 1. How does `ExpireAndSaveTrades` class related to it. 2. What exactly is happened inside `Dao` class' methods (if there are calls to some other classes, please post them too)

Comment: @amseager - updated the question, I am using spring-data for DB operations

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring @Retryable with stateful Hibernate Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54559143/spring-retryable-with-stateful-hibernate-object)

Comment: Thanks @crizzis - I did go though this post..but I couldn't make it to work. Let me try again and check

Comment: With stateful retry, only state is maintained; you have to call the method until successful or retries are exhausted; see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing retries within transaction; this is wrong and will produce the results you are seeing; you need to swap it around and perform transactions within retries. This is why you get the rollback error when not using stateful.

If you use stateful retry, all `@Retryable` does is retain state; the caller of the retryable has to keep calling until success or retry exhaustion.

**EDIT**

Here is an example of using stateful retry

```java
@Component
class ServiceCaller {

    @Autowired
    Service service;

    public void call() {
        try {
            this.service.process();
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            System.out.println("retrying...");
            call();
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }

}

@Component
class Service {

    @Autowired
    Retryer retryable;

    @Transactional
    public void process() {
        retryable.invoke();
    }

}

@Component
class Retryer {

    @Retryable(maxAttempts = 3, stateful = true)
    public void invoke() {
        System.out.println("Invoked");
        throw new IllegalStateException("failed");
    }

    @Recover
    public void recover(IllegalStateException e) {
        System.out.println("Retries exhausted");
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

```
Invoked
retrying...
Invoked
retrying...
Invoked
retrying...
Retries exhausted
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed
    at com.example.demo.Retryer.recover(So67197577Application.java:84) ~[classes/:na]
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed
```

and, without the `@Recover` method...

```
Invoked
retrying...
Invoked
retrying...
Invoked
retrying...
...
Caused by: org.springframework.retry.ExhaustedRetryException: Retry exhausted after last attempt with no recovery path; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed
```

Comment: unfortunately I cannot swap it around and why is it wrong to do it this way ?

Comment: I didn't fully read the question; my explanation is why you are getting the rolled back exception. With stateful retry, your code has to keep calling; there is no automatic retry invocation; in your case the caller of `expireAndSaveTrades` needs to keep calling until either success, or retries are exhausted. I edited the answer.

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: Thank yo so much. So in this example, you are using `@Retryable` but you are not specifying which exception to retry at that point. So upon an exception, the control will go back to the parent class's catch block. In short, this can also be achieved by using `@Retryable` in the parent class i.e. in ServiceCaller class and that way you dont have to  write try/catch block.

Comment: what I was trying to achieve here was if there are multiple db operations (say 6 DB calls are happening), within the Retryer.invoke method and lets say the last DB operation failed, then instead of retrying all of them again, I just wanted to retry that specific DB call to save time

Comment: No. If there are non-retryable exceptions, the retries are exhausted immediately. With stateful, your code must do the retry calls.

Comment: You cannot do that if all the db ops are run in the same transaction. If one is rolled back, they all will be.